# jQuery steps with Bootstrap validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a form which validates with bootstrap validator:

http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/

I want to separate this form into steps and have each the inputs in each step validate when the next button is clicked and if it validates, then go to step 2.

I believe this can be achieved if we can combine jQuery steps and Bootstrap validator.

http://www.jquery-steps.com/

Like this comment suggests:
https://github.com/1000hz/bootstrap-validator/issues/491

I have been trying to do this but unsuccessful so far. Is there a way?

I have made a JSFiddle for this:

https://jsfiddle.net/mpLpwt7L/

This is my code so far:

```
        <div class="steps-nav">
            <div class="row bs-wizard" style="border-bottom: 0;">
                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step complete step-active">
                  <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                  <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">
                    1
                  </a>
                  <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Vehicle details</div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step">
                  <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                  <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">
                    2
                  </a>
                  <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Location</div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step">
                  <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                 <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">
                    3
                  </a>
                  <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Type of Wash</div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-3 bs-wizard-step disabled">
                  <div class="progress"><div class="progress-bar"></div></div>
                 <a href="#" class="bs-wizard-dot">
                    4
                  </a>
                  <div class="bs-wizard-info text-center">Bills</div>
                </div>
            </div><!-- end bs-wizard -->

        </div><!-- end steps-nav -->
    </div><!-- end container -->
</header><!-- end header -->

<main id="main">
  <div class="container">
     <form role="form" class="order-form" method="post">
                <div class="row setup-content" id="step-1">
                    <div class="steps-inner">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <h3>Vehicle Details</h3>
                          <p>
                            Tell us what are we washing
                          </p>
                          <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <!--<label></label>-->
                                    <input type="text" name="vehicle_year" class="form-control" placeholder="Car Year" data-error="Car Year is required" required />
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="vehicle_make" class="form-control" data-error="Make is required" placeholder="Make" required />
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-4">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="vehicle_model" class="form-control" data-error="Model is required" placeholder="Model" required />
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                            </div>
                          </div><!-- end row -->

                           <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="vehicle_color" class="form-control" data-error="Color is required" placeholder="Color" required />
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <input type="text" name="plate_number" class="form-control" data-error="Plate number is required" placeholder="Lic Plate" required />
                                    <div class="help-block with-errors"></div>
                                </div><!-- end form-group -->
                            </div>
                          </div><!-- end row -->

                          <div class="text-center form-submit">
                               <button class="btn next-btn" type="submit">Next <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end steps-inner -->
                </div><!-- end setup-content -->

                <div class="row setup-content" id="step-2">
                    <div class="steps-inner">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                          <h3>Location</h3>
                          <p>
                            Tell us where it is
                          </p>

                          <p class="map-address">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                            <input type="text" name="address" id="address_autocomplete" placeholder="Enter Your Address"  />
                          </p>                      

                          <div class="text-center form-submit">
                               <button class="btn next-btn" type="submit">Next <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
                          </div>
                    </div><!-- end steps-inner -->
                </div>
            </div><!-- end setup-content -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think bootstrap validator isn't the best solution for your needs. Try to use [Twitter Bootstrap Wizard](http://vinceg.github.io/twitter-bootstrap-wizard/examples/validation.html) which includes **wizard** **+** **form** **validation** so you can implement it easily.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try and use it and see if it can work for my given situation. +1